# Draw Cone Go JS base on angle and degree

Tags: gojs

Any ideas on how to go about this dynamically base on angle and degree?
[image]

I've got this for drawing a simple bezier line.

```
 var KAPPA = 4 * ((Math.sqrt(2) - 1) / 3);
    go.Shape.defineFigureGenerator("Cone3", function(shape, w, h) {
      var geo = new go.Geometry();
      var cpxOffset = KAPPA * .5;
      var cpyOffset = KAPPA * .1;
      var fig = new go.PathFigure(0, .9 * h, true);
      geo.add(fig);
    
      fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, .5 * w, 0));
      fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, w, .9 * h));
      fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Bezier, .5 * w, h, w, (.9 + cpyOffset) * h,
        (.5 + cpxOffset) * w, h));
      fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Bezier, 0, .9 * h, (.5 - cpxOffset) * w, h,
        0, (.9 + cpyOffset) * h).close());
      geo.spot1 = new go.Spot(.25, .5);
      geo.spot2 = new go.Spot(.180, .97);
      return geo;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is given in this sample: https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/SectorReshaping.html

```
    function makeSector(radius, angle, sweep) {  // Geometry converter for the node's "LAMP" Shape
      var start = new go.Point(radius, 0).rotate(angle);
      // this is much more efficient than calling go.GraphObject.make:
      var geo = new go.Geometry()
        .add(new go.PathFigure(radius + start.x, radius + start.y)  // start point
          .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Arc,
            angle, sweep,  // angles
            radius, radius,  // center
            radius, radius))  // radius
          .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, radius, radius).close()))
        .add(new go.PathFigure(0, 0))  // make sure the Geometry always includes the whole circle
        .add(new go.PathFigure(2 * radius, 2 * radius));  // even if only a small sector is "lit"
      return geo;
    }
```

The sample's purpose, though, is to demonstrate a tool to allow the user to interactively modify such shapes.  I don't know if you need such functionality.